# What is the format of the Remap XML file for IKVM?

Tags: xml, ikvm

In [this article](http://weblog.ikvm.net/CommentView.aspx?guid=b9b950c5-eb34-4b81-975a-1c95492736fb) Jeroen explains an example of using an XML file to remap Java Bean getters and setters to .NET Properties.

What would the XML file look like if I wanted to, say, remap a Java method called `showDialog()` to `ShowDialog()` in .NET? Has anyone worked with the remapping option before? Any idea where to get information on how it works other than inspecting the [remapper.cs](http://ikvm.cvs.sourceforge.net/ikvm/ikvm/ikvmc/remapper.cs?revision=1.16&view=markup) source code?

**Edit #1** - Found something that definitely helps a bit: the [map.xml](http://ikvm.cvs.sourceforge.net/ikvm/ikvm/openjdk/map.xml?revision=1.41&view=markup) file in the OpenJDK folder seems to have the same format.

**Edit #2** Ouch. 7 views in 16 hours. :-) I have officially reached the fringes of SO knowledge... ;)

Comment: Is this question answered?  It's been on the unanswered list for a while...

Comment: no it isn't - the format of the xml file is still not clear. i ended up solving the underlying problem (capitalizing methods) with a ProGuard obfuscation using a custom mapping file for that...and THEN converting everything to .NET using IKVM.

Comment: if you need a answer, i spend a bounty...?

Comment: @Epaga Why not answer your own question?

Comment: because i only found a workaround, not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you will have to use [MapFileGenerator.java](http://www.frijters.net/MapFileGenerator.java) mentioned in the article referred ;-)

More info can be found on BeanInfo [here](https://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/javabeans/introspection/index.html).

Comment: yeah sorry but that's not helpful. Like I said, I want to remap method names, not only bean properties.

So I need to understand the XML schema for the mapping.

Good try. Sort of. ;-)